# Effective Access Active Directory Object Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get effective permissions of certain active directory users on various Active Directory objects. I can see these permissions from the UI - [image]

I am trying to get this using Powershell. I have already tried `dsacls` and `Get-Acls` but these don't give effective permissions. *These both give "who has access/permissions" which is not the same as "who has what effective permissions"*. These also don't list out all the granular details that would provide context around the effective access.

Any pointers on how this can be achieved programmatically would be really appreciated.

Update -

Effective permissions here would mean which permissions are allowed to the object in reality based on inheritances or other rules set at a different level.

For example -

All the properties in the below example are not visible with Get-ACL.
[image]

Another example of what Get-Acl shows while the UI tells differently is when I pulled permissions for domain admins on one of the OUs via Get-ACL , after resolving the values in ObjectType and InheritedObjectType (use get-effective access function mentioned by Santiago Squarzon) I get -

[image]

While the UI effective access shows-

[image]

My end goal is to get all the permission in the above screenshot using powershell.

Comment: `Get-Acl` should give you that information. Use the grouping operator (..) to expose that code property. `(Get-ACL .\).Access`. Can you clarify what you mean by "*effective permissions*"?

Comment: `All Objects (Full Control)` in the ACL you're showing means full control over the `ActiveDirectoryRights`, it is not the same as **Effective Access** on **Advanced Security Settings**. Compare the result of an `IdentityReference` the you know has full control with the one you're showing, you'll see the difference. In addition, you're not showing if there is other ACL denying `Full Control` over that `IdentityReference`. As I said in my answer, you need to know how to read the output of `Get-ACL`.

Comment: This was the only entry for domain controllers. It didn't have any deny rules. I didn't include the identity reference as I wanted to avoid censoring the image. Both the screen shots show the result of the same identity reference.

Comment: Just for reference, I edited my answer to show you how **Full Control** looks like compared with **WriteDACL**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty close to what you're looking for. [Source](https://github.com/santysq/Get-EffectiveAccess) for more details. Access Control Lists with `Get-ACL` are not as easy to read as ***Effective Access*** on ***Advanced Security Settings*** and I don't think there is a way around that. I do think that, once used to it, `Get-ACL` gives a lot more details when you know what you're looking for \ filter the ACLs to get what you're looking for.

#### Code

```
function Get-EffectiveAccess {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidatePattern('(?:(CN=([^,]*)),)?(?:((?:(?:CN|OU)=[^,]+,?)+),)?((?:DC=[^,]+,?)+)$')]
        [alias('DistinguishedName')]
        [string] $Identity,

        [parameter()]
        [alias('Domain')]
        [string] $Server
    )

    begin {
        $guid    = [guid]::Empty
        $GUIDMap = @{}

        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Server')) {
            $domain = Get-ADRootDSE -Server $Server
        }
        else {
            $domain = Get-ADRootDSE
        }

        $params = @{
            SearchBase  = $domain.schemaNamingContext
            LDAPFilter  = '(schemaIDGUID=*)'
            Properties  = 'name', 'schemaIDGUID'
            ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
        }
        $adObjParams = @{
            Properties = 'nTSecurityDescriptor'
        }

        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Server')) {
            $params['Server']  = $Server
            $adObjParams['Server'] = $Server
        }
        $schemaIDs = Get-ADObject @params

        $params['SearchBase'] = "CN=Extended-Rights,$($domain.configurationNamingContext)"
        $params['LDAPFilter'] = '(objectClass=controlAccessRight)'
        $params['Properties'] = 'name', 'rightsGUID'
        $extendedRigths = Get-ADObject @params

        foreach($i in $schemaIDs) {
            if(-not $GUIDMap.ContainsKey([guid] $i.schemaIDGUID)) {
                $GUIDMap.Add([guid] $i.schemaIDGUID, $i.name)
            }
        }
        foreach($i in $extendedRigths) {
            if(-not $GUIDMap.ContainsKey([guid] $i.rightsGUID)) {
                $GUIDMap.Add([guid] $i.rightsGUID, $i.name)
            }
        }
    }

    process {
        try {
            $adObjParams['Identity'] = $Identity
            $object = Get-ADObject @adObjParams

            foreach($acl in $object.nTSecurityDescriptor.Access) {
                if($guid.Equals($acl.ObjectType)) {
                    $objectType = 'All Objects (Full Control)'
                }
                elseif($GUIDMap.ContainsKey($acl.ObjectType)) {
                    $objectType = $GUIDMap[$acl.ObjectType]
                }
                else {
                    $objectType = $acl.ObjectType
                }

                if($guid.Equals($acl.InheritedObjectType)) {
                    $inheritedObjType = 'Applied to Any Inherited Object'
                }
                elseif($GUIDMap.ContainsKey($acl.InheritedObjectType)) {
                    $inheritedObjType = $GUIDMap[$acl.InheritedObjectType]
                }
                else {
                    $inheritedObjType = $acl.InheritedObjectType
                }

                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name                  = $object.Name
                    IdentityReference     = $acl.IdentityReference
                    AccessControlType     = $acl.AccessControlType
                    ActiveDirectoryRights = $acl.ActiveDirectoryRights
                    ObjectType            = $objectType
                    InheritedObjectType   = $inheritedObjType
                    InheritanceType       = $acl.InheritanceType
                    IsInherited           = $acl.IsInherited
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Examples

- Get the *Effective Access* of the Organizational Unit named `ExampleOU`:

```bash
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq 'ExampleOU'" |
    Get-EffectiveAccess | Out-GridView
```

- Get the *Effective Access* of the Organizational Unit named `ExampleOU` on a Trusted Domain:

```bash
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq 'ExampleOU'" -Server trustedDomain |
    Get-EffectiveAccess -Server trustedDomain | Out-GridView
```

- Same as above but using the OU's `DistinguishedName` attribute:

```bash
Get-EffectiveAccess -Identity 'OU=ExampleOU,DC=domainName,DC=com' | Out-GridView
```

- Store the *Effective Access* of the group named `exampleGroup` in a variable:

```bash
$effectiveAccess = Get-ADGroup exampleGroup | Get-EffectiveAccess
```

- Get the *Effective Access* of the first 10 OUs found in the Domain:

```bash
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Select -First 10 |
    Get-EffectiveAccess | Out-GridView
```

#### Sample

For reference, this is how **Full Control** looks like with `Get-ACL`

[image: fullcontrol]

Compared with **BUILTIN\Administrators** which has write permissions on this OU but not **Full Control**

[image: writepermissions]

Comment: Thank you for providing with the information and the code this is useful. Based on my initial testing this gives more information than the by resolving the values in the ObjectType and InheritedObjectType. It still is not able to get the permissions that you can see in the Effective Access.
Also with get-acls that this function uses permissions like Write ObjectSid, Read ObjectSid etc. are not visible. (will update the question) Also properties like Write Property does not tell me exactly which properties is a user given access while which property is denied.

Comment: I agree that this does not reflect the effective access tab, however it helped me quickly find a misconfigured OU by comparing the configuration of two OUs with this function, so it can be a valuable tool still! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try [PowerShellAccessControl](https://github.com/rohnedwards/PowerShellAccessControl) module I think the details for this module are covered in this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/G4bptl-H8PU?t=2423) with the function `Get-EffectiveAccess`. This should help you get the information. The module has been deleted from the [Microsoft's PS Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShellAccessControl-d3be7b83/file/136752/1/PowerShellAccessControl_v4.0_preview_20150417.zip). I am not sure how you might be able to install the module from Github, I couldn't try it as I am working with a Mac.