# Permissions report for AD groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a table of permissions out of some groups that I have in AD. I'm pretty new to PowerShell and I'm not sure what I want is even possible.

So far I've been able to select the groups that I want by using

```
Get-ADUser -Identity groupname
```

And I can see the info pulled up in the response from PowerShell, but from there I've hit a huge dead-end with piping the result into anything that would let me see the permissions for that group.

Comment: What kind of permissions? Something like `Get-ADGroup`?

Comment: Permission are not stored alongside the group - they're stored in the systems that own the resources being protected. So to figure out if AD group G has permission to delete file F on domain member SRV1, you need to go interrogate the file system on SRV1 about the permissions in effect on file F. It's not going to be in AD

Comment: Might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/67698076/15339544

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the permissions to the group itself (for example, who is allowed to modify the group).

You can use [`Get-Acl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl) (ACL stands for Access-Control List), which is used for getting permissions from files as well. To direct it to AD, you use the `AD:` drive, along with the distinguished name of the AD object. For example:

```
(Get-Acl "AD:CN=SomeGroup,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com").Access
```

If you don't know the distinguished name, you can get that from your call to `Get-ADGroup` (I assume you meant to use `Get-ADGroup`, not `Get-ADUser` like you put in your question).

```
$group = Get-ADGroup groupname
(Get-Acl "AD:$($group.distinguishedName)").Access
```

More reading here: [Understanding Get-ACL and AD Drive Output](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/understanding-get-acl-and-ad-drive-output/)

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Yes I was using Get-ADGroup. This is exactly what I was looking for!