# Need guidance with the below AD Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adgroup, memberof

*I'm having issues trying to pull the members of the security tab of each group in AD.....can someone help pls?*

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties name, security | select security, @{n=’Security’; e= { ( $_.Security | % { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }}
```

Error below:

```
Get-ADGroup : One or more properties are invalid.
Parameter name: security
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties security | select security, @{n=’Se ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The [attribute you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-ntsecuritydescriptor) is named `nTSecurityDescriptor`. It's also a bit unclear what you mean by "members of the security tab" - I assume you want to list all accounts/groups/principals for which an access control entry exists on the group object in AD? Don't you want additional information? Like, what permissions are being configured, and whether they're being allowed or denied?

Comment: The expression on your calculated property would be what I believe you're looking for `$_.nTSecurityDescriptor.Access.IdentityReference -join ', '` after querying the property Mathias mentioned above

Comment: If you use the Active Directory provider (ie `cd ad:`) you can just use `Get-Acl` like `$Groups=Get-ADGroup -filter * | %{Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Security' -NotePropertyValue (Get-Acl $_.distinguishedname) -passthr}`

Comment: Yes, I would like to have additional info like each member of the security tab what permissions they have ( this would be what Im trying to get to) but first need to export all members of each group's security tab....not sure if t makes sense!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67698076/15339544 this might be useful

Comment: Sorry, Im not following @The

Comment: try the function from the answer linked before, `Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Get-EffectiveAccess` should be what you're looking for

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - would it be something like this ?

Get-ADGroup -filter * | Get-EffectiveAccess | %{Add-Member -InputObject $_.nTSecurityDescriptor.Access.IdentityReference 'Security' -NotePropertyValue (Get-Acl $_.distinguishedname) -passthr}

Comment: No, just the command I provided before, that function does everything for you

Comment: yea, it doesn't recognize the Get-EffectiveAccess..

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - can you pls show me how I would include the Get-Acl command, not familiar with it? Also, do you want me to use PS or AD Module? Preferably I like the members and their permissions, so your advise makes more sense to run...

thank you in advance and much appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Get-Acl` cmdlet in conjunction with the AD provider. If you're getting all of your groups, you must be using the ActiveDirectory module, so you should have the provider available as well. The provider allows you to browse through Active Directory similarly to a file system. So first thing to do is swap to that provider:

```
cd AD:
```

Then you can get your groups like you intended to:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter *
```

Now you can loop through those and use the distinguishedName to get the ACLs for each group object. Now, there's a few ways to do this, I'm going to use `Add-Member`. AD Group objects like to try and make any new members ADPropertySets, so we'll be using the `-force` parameter to make sure it is a NoteProperty.

```
$Groups | ForEach-Object{
    $ACLs = Get-Acl -Path $_.distinguishedName
    Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Security' -NotePropertyValue $ACL.Access -Force
}
```

Then you can just do something like `$Groups|Format-Table Name,Security` or something.